# photoshop select all text layers in a group

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I know you can select all text layers using 'select similar layers', but is it possible to limit that selection to just the layers within a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the select similar layers function ignores the groups they are in. A (not-so-recommended, but might-apply) alternative would be use smart objects instead of groups, and "enter" them to select layer types. This will of course mean you can't work with them in context, but if you are working with large groups it might apply to your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no option in Photoshop